# Setting Width of Border doesn't affect ActualWidth until I call InvalidateMeasure

Tags: wpf

I have a Border in a ContentControl. The Width property has a binding to a property in my viewmodel.
A value is set in the viewmodel property, which correctly changes the Width property of the Border. However, the ActualWidth of the Border doesn't change until I either resize the window, or call InvalidateMeasure() on the Border.

I don't see why this is necessary.

I had a look with ILSpy in the code of FrameworkElement.Width and saw these lines in FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged():

```
    if (frameworkPropertyMetadata.AffectsMeasure && (!BypassLayoutPolicies || (property != WidthProperty && property != HeightProperty)))
    {
        InvalidateMeasure();
    }
```

AffectsMeasure is True on the Width property, so I would expect InvalidateMeasure to be called automatically when the values changes, except that it doesn't do that for the Width and Height properties. Why is that?

Comment: Not sure what `BypassLayoutPolicies` is, but `Width` and `Height` are specifically excluded by that condition otherwise.

Comment: Exactly, and I don't understand why.
I think BypassLayoutPolicies is false unless it's a Window. So then it should work in my case, and I don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: Most likely there is another explanation, but you haven't posted enough information for us to help you.